# Python import text array with varying row length and convert non values to zeros

Tags: python, matlab, file

sorry if thisis a little long. I have a .txt file with values of differing row lengths and would like to read the file as a matrix in python. The file contents are something similar to:

```
1
1
1
6
7,8,3
6,6,8
8,7,1
```

I want to read the file and then populate the rows with zero's (similar to Matlabs dlmread()) to match the max row length. The methods i've tried either give me a single string or a matrix without the zero's. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
File_3min = open(File_3min, 'r')
array = File_3min.readlines()
data = []

for i in array:
    data.append(i)

numpy_fillna(data)
```

Function to add in zero's to rows which dont satisfy the max row length.

```
import numpy as np


def numpy_fillna(data):
    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in data])
    mask = np.arange(lens.max()) < lens[:,None]
    out = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=data.dtype)
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(data)
    return out
```

Comment: you have a typo in here `The methods i've tried either give me the Any help on how to do this file as a single string or a matrix without the 0's. ` which makes what you're asking a little unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open the file with a context `with` statement so that it will close properly after you're done with it, just for good practice

```
with open(File_3min, 'r') as File_3min:
    lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in File_3min]
```

Notice that i also used `split(',')` to get lists out of each line and `strip()` to get all the lines without whitespace and newline chars

Now you can get the maximum length of the lines like this:

```
max_len = max(len(line) for line in lines)
```

Now that you have both the maximum length of a line and the number of lines (with `len(lines)`) you can create a numpy array of zeros of the right shape, later to be filled:

```
my_array = np.zeros([len(lines), max_len])
```

Now to actually fill the array you can do this, which isn't pretty, but it works:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    my_array[i, :len(line)] = line
```

Now all you have in `my_array` are lines/rows of equal length, padded by zeros, of what were once the rows in the file.

Comment: Thanks very much the code and suggestions worked perfectly, I really appreciate it. And thank you for the clearly written notes, really helped in understanding the code

Answer (score 0):

damn, beat me to it. mine is similar:

```
array = """1
1
1
6
7,8,3
6,6,8
8,7,1""".split('\n')

data = []

for i in array:
    data.append([float(x) for x in i.strip().split(',')])

data_max = max([len(x) for x in data])

out = np.array([x + list(np.zeros(data_max - len(x))) for x in data])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, its always good to have different methods to help in my own learning. Appreciate it!!